# Grouping array of objects by property value with JSONata

Tags: jsonata

I want to transform this array of objects:

```json
{
  "Phone": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "0203 544 1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "01962 001234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "01962 001235"
    },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": "077 7700 1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

into an array of objects, which groups phone numbers by type:

```json
[
    {
        "type": "home",
        "numbers": ["0203 544 1234"]
    },
    {
        "type": "office",
        "numbers": ["01962 001234", "01962 001235"]
    },
    {
        "type": "mobile",
        "numbers": ["077 7700 1234"]
    }
]
```

with JSONata. Any hints?

I've tried this:

```json
Phone{type: number}
```

But that leads to a different structure:

```json
{
  "home": "0203 544 1234",
  "office": [
    "01962 001234",
    "01962 001235"
  ],
  "mobile": "077 7700 1234"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track, and you just need to apply additional transformation at the end to transform the grouped object into an array:

```
{
  "Phone": Phone{
    type: number
  } ~> $each(function($value, $key) {{
    "type": $key,
    "number": $value
  }})
}
```

Check it out on the Stedi playground: https://stedi.link/JO7kBed

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I needed. JSONata is awesome but sometimes quite tricky. I changed it a little (https://stedi.link/pfE3x7D), so single numbers are also in arrays.